# expected primary-expression before '||'

Tags: c++

newbie here messing around and i encountered this error: expected primary-expression before '||' token. checked ever post I could find with similar issues but with no luck.
any help greatly appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

 string txt;

 while(txt == "") || (txt == " ");
 {
     cout << "Please enter the sentence you want to translate.";
     cin >> txt;
 }
}
```

Comment: Unlike python, the conditional statements after keywords like `while` and `if` must be fully enclosed in parentheses.

Comment: Note: The `>>` operator typically (and definitely in the case of a `std::string`) stops  as and returns what it has gathered soon as it finds whitespace. This means `cin >> txt;` will read a single word, not a sentence. [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) is likely the best tool to use here.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for `while` is (roughly):

```
while(condition)
    block
```

where `block` is either a single statement or multiple statements enclosed in `{` and `}`.

There is no semicolon after the condition and the condition needs to be wrapped in parentheses.

I recommend you to learn C++ from [a good introductory book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Your instructional material should explain to you the syntax of grammar constructs and you should not try to guess it.

Comment: thank you so much for your fast reply. cant believe how much time i wasted on such a simple mistake

Comment: @panos See my edit. If you don't have one already, use a good book that teaches you the syntax correctly. I don't know how you got the idea that there should be a semicolon after the condition or that there don't need to be parentheses around it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting this error message from the compiler is because it is seeing the || operator and expecting to find two "primary expressions", one on each side of the ||. In your case, `while(txt == "")` is not a primary expression.

from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/primary-expressions?view=vs-2019, a primary expression is:

```
100 // literal
'c' // literal
this // in a member function, a pointer to the class instance
::func // a global function
::operator + // a global operator function
::A::B // a global qualified name
( i + 1 ) // a parenthesized expression
```

It can be confusing because the compiler looks at your code differently than you do and can have a hard time understanding what you are attempting to write even when it seems obvious to you.

What you were trying to do, write a while loop, is spelled like this in C++

```cpp
while(condition)
  statement

//or

while(condition)
{
  statements...               
}
```

The condition can be a compound expression like the one you used

```cpp
while((txt == "") || (txt == " "))
{
  cout << "Please enter the sentence you want to translate.";
  cin >> txt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try surrounding the entire `while` condition with parentheses:

```
while ((txt == "") || (txt == " ")) {
    ...
}
```